# Failed to display hokuyo node message on Rviz in Virtual machine

Tags: ros, rviz, hokuyo-node, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use parallel Desktop 6.0 on macbook to install ubuntu 11.04.

I run the following instructions:

```
  rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node
  rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find hokuyo_node`/hokuyo_test.vcg
```

result:

[image: image description]

Orbit views:

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

Obviously it is not correct.
Because the laser data point is not only a line.

When I try the same laser range finder at the other computer,it works normal.

Like this screen shot:

[image: image description]

How to fixed it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10980/failed-to-display-hokuyo-node-message-on-rviz-in-virtual-machine./) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-23**:
I have updated the original post to add the normal picture of laser range finder.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-23**:
Can you clarify what exactly is incorrect about what you see?  I'm having trouble from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks to me like an instance of the [bug described here, where point clouds are not being rotated correctly.](http://answers.ros.org/question/2144/rviz-sensor-data-does-not-rotate)

The other reporter was also running Ubuntu on a Mac.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2011-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try changing the view dropdown to "orbit" and rotating the camera around the laser's origin. Looks to me like in your first image the camera is in the same plane as the laser, but in the second the camera is giving you a top down view of the data. "Orbit" mode will let you change the camera angles and see if that makes a difference.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-23**:
I updated the original post, and I have changed to orbit views,but the result is the same.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-23**:
Ah, okay, I see what he was referring to as "wrong" now.  I think that it's just an orbit issue as well.  I have had no issues with Parallels/Natty/Snow Leopard that I can think of.